# How to make precise function annotation after Partial applied

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, functools

Given a function:

```py
def foobar(foo: int, bar: str, spam: SpamService) -> str:
    return spam.serve(foo, bar)
```

This function, similar in look to FastAPI endpoints, define two parameters as "normal" parameters, and one "Service", an abstract class. I want to "reuse" the `foobar` function like I reuse a FastAPI endpoint in a router, and register `n` "version" of the function given `n` dependencies.

Example:

```py
foobar_rabbit = inject(foobar, RabbitService)
foobar_snake = inject(foobar, SnakeService)
foobar_rabbit(1, "rabot")
foobar_snake(2, "sniky")
```

I can use `functools.partial` to do that, but I want the dependancy to be injected as a correct parameter without relying on position or keyword args.

This mean that a function that require two dependencies like:

```py
def foobar(foo: int, egg: EggService, spam: SpamService) -> str:
    return spam.serve(foo, egg.do_stuff())
```

Can be registered like this:

```py
foobar_1 = inject(foobar, SpamService1, EggService2)
foobar_1_ = inject(foobar, EggService2, SpamService1)  # result in the same Partial
```

To do that, I did this code (should run as is on python 3.11, no external dep):

```py
import abc
import functools
import inspect
import typing


class Service(abc.ABC):
    ...


class ServiceA(Service):
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method_a(a: int) -> str:
        """
        This method do something.
        """


class ServiceA1(ServiceA):
    @staticmethod
    def method_a(a: int) -> str:
        return f"A1: {a}"


def inject(
        func: typing.Callable,
        *services: typing.Type[Service]
) -> functools.partial:
    annotations = inspect.get_annotations(func)
    del annotations["return"]

    bind_services = {
        key: service
        for key, value in annotations.items()
        if issubclass(value, Service)
        for service in services
        if issubclass(service, value)
    }

    return functools.partial(func, **bind_services)


def foobar(foo: int, spam: ServiceA) -> str:
    return spam.method_a(foo)


foobar_A1 = inject(foobar, ServiceA1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foobar_A1(1))  # A1: 1
```

The issue is the signature of `foobar_A1`. If I don't send any arguments, Pycharm won't raise a warning, and mypy won't find any error.

I tried many alternative using `typing.TypeVar` for example but nothing works.

Here an example of a non working solution:

```py
_SERVICE = typing.TypeVar("_SERVICE", bound=Service)
_RETURN = typing.TypeVar("_RETURN")

def inject(
        func: typing.Callable[[..., _SERVICE], _RETURN],
        *services: typing.Type[Service]
) -> functools.partial[typing.Callable[[_SERVICE, ...], _RETURN]]:
```

But mypy complains and it's not creating the expected signature (I'm not used to this kind of annotation wizardry yet).

Expected signature: `(foo: int) -> str`

Comment: This is impossible to express in the Python type system. `inject` can accept a function `f` with an arbitrary signature and returns a function `g` with a **subset** of the parameters of `f`. But _which exact_ parameters remain in `g` depends on which of them are of a specific type. The best you could do is have `inject` return the same exact signature as `f`. Or you restrict yourself to a **fixed** number of "injectable" parameters that must be at the very beginning of the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my initial comment, the current Python typing system is unfortunately not powerful enough to make your `inject` function look the way you want. (Just like there is no way to *properly* annotate [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).)

It can accept a function `f` with an arbitrary signature and returns a function `g` with a *subset* of the parameters of `f`. But which *exact* parameters of `f` remain in `g` depends on which of them were of a specific type. Even with generics ([`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) and [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec)) you cannot express this fully in Python.

---

### 1) Simple alternatives

What you *can* do is tell type checkers that `inject` returns a function of the same type as the function that you pass to it:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


class Service:
    ...


def inject(func: Callable[P, R], *services: type[Service]) -> Callable[P, R]:  # type: ignore[empty-body]
    ...


class ServiceA(Service):
    @staticmethod
    def meth(n: int) -> str:
        return "a" * n


def foo(n: int, spam: type[ServiceA]) -> str:
    return spam.meth(n)


foo_a = inject(foo, ServiceA)
reveal_type(foo_a)  # def (n: builtins.int, spam: Type[ServiceA]) -> builtins.str
```

Now if all you want to do with the `inject` function is reuse it **internally** in your own package without documenting/exposing it publicly, you can simply *tell* a type checker, what type the injected "partial" functions have by annotating them accordingly. Here you have a couple of options.

##### a) Using [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable)

Knowing what the call signature of your injected functions will be, you can simply annotate them with a corresponding `Callable` subtype:

```py
...

def foo(n: int, spam: type[ServiceA]) -> str:
    return spam.meth(n)


foo_a: Callable[[int], str] = inject(foo, ServiceA)
reveal_type(foo_a)  # def (builtins.int) -> builtins.str
```

That assignment will of course cause a type checker to raise an error because it will see that `Callable[[int], str]` is not a supertype of what `inject` returns in that call, namely `Callable[[int, Type[ServiceA]], str]`.

But again, since you are just doing this for your own benefit, you do not need to worry about that too much. You can either 1) silence the type checker with a [`type: ignore`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_inference_and_annotations.html?highlight=ignore#silencing-type-errors) directive or 2) force it to accept the type by [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)ing it explicitly:

```py
...

def foo(n: int, spam: type[ServiceA]) -> str:
    return spam.meth(n)


from typing import cast


foo_a_1: Callable[[int], str] = inject(foo, ServiceA)  # type: ignore[assignment]
foo_a_2 = cast(Callable[[int], str], inject(foo, ServiceA))
reveal_type(foo_a_1)  # def (builtins.int) -> builtins.str
reveal_type(foo_a_2)  # def (builtins.int) -> builtins.str
```

Both of those work, but the solution has a few drawbacks. `Callable` is not expressive enough to to define parameter *names* (notice how the revealed type is missing the name `n` as opposed to the very first example). You also cannot make distinctions between positional/keyword arguments at all. If those are issues for you, you might want to use a different approach.

##### b) Using a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)

To have more fine-grained control over the call signature, you can define your own protocol for the function in question. Say for example you wanted the `n` parameter in `foo` to be positional-*only*:

```py
...

def foo(n: int, /, spam: type[ServiceA]) -> str:
    return spam.meth(n)


from typing import Protocol, cast


class PartialFoo(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, n: int) -> str: ...


class PartialFoo(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, n: int, /) -> str: ...


foo_a = cast(PartialFoo, inject(foo, ServiceA))
reveal_type(foo_a)         # PartialFoo
foo_a_output = foo_a(1)
reveal_type(foo_a_output)  # builtins.str
foo_a(1, ServiceA)         # error: Too many arguments for "__call__" of "PartialFoo"  [call-arg]
foo_a(n=1)                 # error: Unexpected keyword argument "n" for "__call__" of "PartialFoo"  [call-arg]
```

Again, you have the option of either using `# type: ignore` or `cast` to enforce your type for `foo_a`; I chose the latter here because PyCharm seems to get confused with the former. (Bug)

As you can see, the drawback here is that Mypy for example will display the type of `foo_a` as `PartialFoo` because that is what we called the protocol and not display something like `(n: int) -> str`. That is of course because a protocol can be much more than *just* a callable, so reducing its representation to the call signature would not make much sense.

But you can also see that it allows you to correctly specify everything about the callable including parameter names and categories.

##### c) Using the [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) hook

Since you only care about influencing static analysis and don't want to affect the runtime at all, another option is to use the `TYPE_CHECKING` constant and effectively create a stub for your function withing a conditional block that is *only* ever looked at by a type checker and never actually executed:

```py
...

def foo(n: int, spam: type[ServiceA]) -> str:
    return spam.meth(n)


from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    def foo_a(n: int) -> str: ...
else:
    foo_a = inject(foo, ServiceA)


reveal_type(foo_a)  # def (n: builtins.int) -> builtins.str
```

Just to be clear: This is a **literal ellipsis** in the body of that `foo_a` stub! There is no need to provide an actual (even a dummy) implementation.

This may be the best option in your case because you still get the default function representation from the type checker for `foo_a` (not a protocol name) and you have all the freedom to express the signature with names and such.

The drawback is that it arguably makes the code a bit harder to read, unless you know what purpose those conditionals serve.

---

### 2) Partial solution/workaround

Depending on how flexible you are with the design of the functions that you want to *pass* to `inject`, you can actually design it in a generic way to make the tricks mentioned above unnecessary.

If you could restrict yourself to making those functions (like `foo` above) take the `Service` classes as their very **first** arguments only, you could write a generic signature for `inject` using [`Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate) and [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) that expresses this "swallowing" of the first *n* function parameters.

The idea is to then define multiple specific [`overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)s for the anticipated/common uses of `inject` and one catch-all signature for the rest.

Something like this could work:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar, overload

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
S1 = TypeVar("S1", bound="Service")
S2 = TypeVar("S2", bound="Service")
S3 = TypeVar("S3", bound="Service")


class Service:
    ...


@overload
def inject(
    func: Callable[Concatenate[type[S1], P], R],
    service1: type[S1],
    /,
) -> Callable[P, R]: ...


@overload
def inject(
    func: Callable[Concatenate[type[S1], type[S2], P], R],
    service1: type[S1],
    service2: type[S2],
    /,
) -> Callable[P, R]: ...


@overload
def inject(
    func: Callable[Concatenate[type[S1], type[S2], type[S3], P], R],
    service1: type[S1],
    service2: type[S2],
    service3: type[S3],
    /,
) -> Callable[P, R]: ...


@overload
def inject(
    func: Callable[P, R],
    /,
    *services: type[Service],
) -> Callable[P, R]: ...


def inject(  # type: ignore[empty-body]
    func: Callable[..., R],
    /,
    *services: type[Service],
) -> Callable[..., R]:
    ...
```

And here is how you would use it:

```py
class ServiceA(Service):
    @staticmethod
    def meth(a: int) -> str:
        return "A..."

class ServiceA1(ServiceA):
    @staticmethod
    def meth(a: int) -> str:
        return f"A1: {a}"

class ServiceA2(ServiceA):
    @staticmethod
    def meth(a: int) -> str:
        return f"A2: {a}"


def foo(spam: type[ServiceA], n: int) -> str:
    return spam.meth(n)

def bar(spam: type[ServiceA], eggs: type[ServiceA], n: int) -> str:
    return spam.meth(n) + eggs.meth(n)


foo_A1 = inject(foo, ServiceA1)
bar_A1 = inject(bar, ServiceA1)
bar_A2 = inject(bar, ServiceA2)
bar_A1_A2 = inject(bar, ServiceA1, ServiceA2)

reveal_type(foo_A1)     # def (n: builtins.int) -> builtins.str
reveal_type(bar_A1)     # def (eggs: Type[ServiceA], n: builtins.int) -> builtins.str
reveal_type(bar_A2)     # def (eggs: Type[ServiceA], n: builtins.int) -> builtins.str
reveal_type(bar_A1_A2)  # def (n: builtins.int) -> builtins.str
```

As you can see, a competent type checker is able to correctly infer the types of those `foo` and `bar` variations after applying the `inject` function because our overloads accommodate those injection calls.

Obviously, this particular version will break down once we want to use it with a function that takes more than three service arguments in the beginning and we will be left in the same situation as the one I laid out in the very beginning.

Also, as I mentioned above, the limitations of `Concatenate` necessitate that the functions passed to `inject` take those service classes *before* all the other arguments. The parameter specification passed to `Concatenate` *must* be at the end, so there is no way to express "swallowing" an argument *after* the generic parameter type variable.

But once again, if *you* are the one in control of where `inject` is used (as opposed to the user of your package), this may be good enough for you.

Comment: I implemented a version of inject with concatenate and services first, so I'm glad we both end-up with this alternative implementation design. IMO, this is the most desirable way of designing inject.
I plan to release a pypi package to do that, and the fact that services needs to be the firsts param can be expressed in the inject funciton name, we can raise warning, etc. Thanks you for your time, this is an extensive and impressive response, that suggested highly detailed alternative typing with pros and cons, amazing.

Comment: @DorianTurba I think you were a little bit mislead with that PyCharm ticket. `overload` is definitely supported. There are just specific bugs with it like with the example for having either `n` arguments or `m` arguments and Pycharm wrongfully allowing anything between `n` and `m` arguments. But that is a niche case and does not apply to what I presented in my answer. So I will roll back your edit and instead mention [the issue you linked here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42137).

Comment: I did a test without the last @overload inject, and the result is less confusing for pycharm, and mypy doesn't raise any error, what do you think?
BTW, I was doing something wrong: `type[ServiceA]` for service annotation, I was using `ServiceA`

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with `inject()` annotation, but we can still create proper annotation for the `foobar_A1` symbol.

## Use stub file `.pyi`

[PEP 484 – Type Hints#Stub Files](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files)

> Stub files are files containing type hints that are only for use by the type checker, not at runtime.

Using stub file `.pyi` allows to explicitly define the signature of the symbol without any convoluted annotatation in the main `.py` file.

### Example based on code snippet of the question:

```py
# .pyi
def foobar_A1(foo: int) -> str: ...
```

### mypy result

If `foobar_A1()` is used without any argument:

```
file.py:line: error: Missing positional argument "foo" in call to "foobar_A1"  [call-arg]
```

## Why this solution is great?

The usecase is to create an SDK i.e. a python package for outside use.
This is a typical usecase of `.pyi` and even a good practice to use such files. This is not a tricks, a workaround, complex or hard to read.
I consider this as a very pythonic solution.

## Alternative

### Create a dummy function

You can calm mypy by creating a dummy function with fake implementation that will be override by the symbol later created.

```py
def foobar_A1(foo: int) -> str:
    c = i
    return ""

foobar_A1 = inject(foobar, ServiceA1)
```

#### Why I reject this alternative

1. Even if it works for mypy, pycharm will still complain about the re-declared symbol without usage.
2. It create a temporary function at runtime for type-checker only. This is why `.pyi` exists in a first place: annotation without runtime.
3. Force you to think about a dummy implementation that will satisfy mypy, and adapt to each function injection. Boilerplate code with the risk of exposing the dummy function in production if the real symbol is renamed or deleted by mistake.

Comment: Stub files solve a problem of *where* to put annotations, not *how* to write the annotations in the first place. The OP's problem highlights the lack of a type-level container to store the arbitrary types of values in an ordinary list.

Comment: Do you think my question was misleading? I was looking exactly at what .ipy is for: a way to be more precise than would be possible using typehint. Similar example in https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading
"which cannot express the relationship between the argument and return types" where pyi can. That was what I was looking for. Provided by the "inject" function wasn't a requirement, I wanted a way to allows typechecker to detect issues when using foobar_A1, for example.

Comment: `.pyi` files use the same syntax as regular `.py` files. Your quote is about using `overload` in place of union types, not about a distinction between stub files and executable files.  (Stub files don't require an actual *implementation* of the overloaded function, like the executable file will, but what you can *express* using `overload` is the same between the two.)

Comment: The main benefit of stub files is the ability to add type hints for a 3rd-party module you don't control. (If you are still using Python 2, which lacks the function-annotation syntax provided by Python 3, you can use a stub file to "hide" that syntax from your Python 2 interpreter.)

Comment: I understand. As explained in the documentation, pyi files can be used to do what you can't using py annotations. I tried to create the definition signature in the same file, but mypy expect actual implementation (Missing return statement), when the implementation is created using the original function. So since it can only be done in .py files at the cost of creating dummy functions at runtime for typechecker purposes only, .pyi is the way to go.

Comment: [what you can't] or can but in a convoluted way

Comment: Not only is this _not_ an answer to your initial question about the `inject` decorator, it is also a needlessly complicated solution, if all you wanted was to to annotate `foobar_A1`, you could have just done that with the various `typing` tools available, such as simply using `Callable` or a callback protocol approach.

Comment: Ignoring `inject`, you can see five different approaches for how you could let the type checker know about a specific function signature in [this Mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=dadefa85775d46fe3f9c6e8ec5944f4c). Essentially you can 1) use a `type: ignore` directive, 2) explicitly [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) the type, or 3) annotate only inside a [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) block.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Thanks for all those proposition. I still found the pyi method easier to scale.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Callable is less informative. Callable signature:  (int) -> str. pyi signature: (i: int) -> str. Also, Callable cannot express keyword only parameter, where pyi can.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I like the protocol approach as a very good alternative, can you create an answer ?

Comment: If you want more fine-grained control like argument _names_ or keyword-only arguments, you should use a `Protocol` (see the `FooPartial` in the Mypy Playground). I don't think you should ever _actively_ try to use stub files. Basically the only reason they exist is to patch untyped packages after the fact.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Since it's possible to have such a good typing in the package (using protocol), I agree. If it's not possible, IMO pyi is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Daniil Fajnberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425137/how-to-make-precise-function-annotation-after-partial-applied/76458872#comment134815736_76433064) comments.

## Use Protocol

```py
def foobar(foo: int, spam: ServiceA) -> str:
    return spam.method_a(foo)

class FoobarPartial(typing.Protocol):
    def __call__(foo: int) -> str:
        ...

foobar_A1: FoobarPartial = inject(foobar, ServiceA1)
```

### Pros

A big one: Since it's incorporated to the `.py` file, Mypy will run over the file instead of ignoring it and using the `.pyi` file.

### Cons

A little one: Mypy error message won't mention the function name.

For calling `foobar_A1("hi")`

```
# pyi
Argument 1 to "foo_nightly" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int" 

# protocol
Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```